# How to identify what exactly happened in the git difftool output

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

I used `git difftool` to get the diff in between 2 commits in `context` format by using

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -c" $1 $2 >>./tempFiles/diffAll.txt
```

here `$1` and `$2` are two commit hashes which are passed as command line arguments to the shell script containing the above code.
In the context format as mentioned in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Context-Format.html#Context-Format), we can easily identify the lines which are modified ( with `!` mark), added (with `+` mark) and deleted( with `-` mark).
part of the output I got from the above is as follows (from latest to oldest),

*latest commit*

```
*** modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml  2016-11-30 12:39:29.882731844 +0530
--- /tmp/i1pg5a_pom.xml 2016-12-06 14:35:03.860669316 +0530
***************
*** 1300,1309 ****
                                      <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.server.feature.group</id>
                                      <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
                                  </feature>
!                                 <feature>
!                                     <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.server.feature.group</id>
!                                     <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
!                                 </feature>

                              </features>
                          </configuration>
--- 1292,1298 ----
                                      <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.server.feature.group</id>
                                      <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
                                  </feature>
! 

                              </features>
                          </configuration>
```

*old commit*

```
*** /tmp/caN3su_pom.xml 2016-12-06 14:35:04.260667699 +0530
--- modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml  2016-11-30 12:39:29.882731844 +0530                         
***************
*** 1292,1298 ****
                                      <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.server.feature.group</id>
                                      <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
                                  </feature>
! 

                              </features>
                          </configuration>
--- 1300,1309 ----
                                      <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.server.feature.group</id>
                                      <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
                                  </feature>
!                                 <feature>
!                                     <id>org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.server.feature.group</id>
!                                     <version>${carbon.identity.auth.version}</version>
!                                 </feature>

                              </features>
                          </configuration>
```

can someone help me to figure out what is actually meant by `!` mark in here.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `!` means the line was changed. You can read the following post: [How to read a patch or diff and understand its structure to apply it manually](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/)

Comment: I know that, but the problem is in the above output,I cannot understand what has happen.